# Unreachable Code - Shouldn't be unreachable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops, arraylist

I want to populate a custom listview, with data read from a file. The file is read using method `ReadPeopleDetails`. This returns an arraylist, which I then, using a loop, take the name string and put it into arraylist people_name.

However apparently the `final ArrayAdapter` adapter line is unreachable, presumably because of the for loop. Could a second pair of eyes tell me why this is?

I would think the for loop will end (length specified by length of arraylist)

Code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_party__people_list, menu);
    ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_list = Readpeopledetails();
    ArrayList<String> people_name = null; ///this will catch the names from the above line, and put them into
    ///an arraylist for use in populating the ListView
    int i = people_list.size();
    //int j; acts as counter in iterator system
    PeopleDetails[] people_array = (PeopleDetails[]) people_list.toArray();
    for(int j = people_list.size(); /*not using termination*/ ; j++ ){
        people_name.add(people_array[j].name);

    }

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.person_list_item, people_name);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: for loop is infinite for loop as you have no exit condition

Comment: You even write it explicitly `/*not using termination*/`. Btw; why not iterate over the `people_list` directly? No need, to convert it to an array. Use a loop like this `for (PeopleDetails detail : people_list) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int j = people_list.size(); /*not using termination - SO LOOP WONT END*/ ; j++ ){
```

This is starting at the end of the list and incrementing from there, so it will go on forever.  You probably want...

```
for(int j = 0; j < i ; j++ ){
```

Comment: yes, I only used `i` as it's already been set to that value by this point.

Answer (score 1):

there is no condition for ending the loop. so it is a infinite loop now.. so the next line is unreachable

do something like

```
for(int j = 0; j< people_list.size(); j++ ){
        people_name.add(people_array[j].name);

    }
```

Seems you are new to java. To learn more about for loop see the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: won't it end at the end of the length of arraylist??? new to java for loops... thanks

Comment: what should I add to end the loop??

Comment: yeah reasonably new... Used to being able to declare it like "1 to i" kind of thing, so got muddled up, and thought I the termination was an extra boolean check system to shorten the loop... Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your loop not terminating, people_name is never assigned an ArrayList so you will get a NullPointerException when you try to call the add method on it.